# sending an xml message to port

Tags: c#, xml, ports

Apologies for the vague question. I am trying to write a c# console application which sends an xml message to a port on which a 3rd party application is listening. The application then sends back another xml message so I need to read that too. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

This [link](https://broadsign.com/docs/11-1-0/developers-intelligent-content/player-api-dynamic-content/player-api/conditions-action/) kind of shows what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Does [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9362959/sending-and-receiving-xml-data-over-tcp) help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not hugely familiar with raw sockets, I'd do something like:

```
    using (var client = new TcpClient())
    {
        client.Connect("host", 2324);
        using (var ns = client.GetStream())
        using (var writer = new StreamWriter(ns))
        {
            writer.Write(xml);
            writer.Write("\r\n\r\n");
            writer.Flush();
        }
        client.Close();
    }
```

For less abstraction, you'd just use a `Socket` instance directly and deal with all the encoding etc manually, just giving `Socket.Send` a `byte[]`.

Comment: Thanks a mil! Worked a charm!

Answer (score 0):

Use xml Linq

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;


namespace ConsoleApplication50
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

                //<?xml version="1.0"?>
                //<active_conditions>
                //  <condition id="12323" name="Sunny"/>
                //  <condition id="13323" name="Warm"/>
                //</active_conditions>

            string header = "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?><active_conditions></active_conditions>";

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(header);

            XElement activeCondition = (XElement)doc.FirstNode;

            activeCondition.Add(new object[] { 
                new XElement("condition", new object[] {
                    new XAttribute("id", 12323),
                    new XAttribute("name", "Sunny")
                }),

                new XElement("condition", new object[] {
                    new XAttribute("id", 13323),
                    new XAttribute("name", "Warm")
                })
            });

            string xml = doc.ToString();

            XDocument doc2 = XDocument.Parse(xml);

            var results = doc2.Descendants("condition").Select(x => new
            {
                id = x.Attribute("id"),
                name = x.Attribute("name")
            }).ToList();

        }
    }

}
```